# Is this subset measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, analysis

Let $F\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, where $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ denotes the set of Borel subsets of $\mathbb R$.
Let $\mathcal C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ (resp. $\mathcal C([0,1],F)$) denote the space of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ (resp. $f:[0,1]\to F$) endowed with the supremum norm.

My Question is the following: **is $\mathcal C([0,1],F)$ a Borel subset of $\mathcal C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ ?**

I can show it is true if $F$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ but I wonder if it remains true for arbitrary measurable $F$.

Comment: You may want to be explicit about what "measurable subset" of $\mathcal C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ means, since at this point you've only told us what $\mathcal C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ is as a normed (linear/vector) space. Probably you want to know if $\mathcal C([0,1],F)$ is a Borel subset of $\mathcal C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ (i.e. a Borel measurable subset). And in the last sentence, "close in $\mathbb R$" probably should be "closed in $\mathbb R$" (unless I'm misunderstanding something).

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, $\mathcal C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ is endowed with its Borel $\sigma$-field, and I want to know whether $\mathcal C([0,1],F)$ is a Borel subset of $\mathcal C([0,1],\mathbb R)$.
And in the last sentence, you should read "closed" in \mathbb R$.